# Adding a Date adapter for Time Cartesian axis from a cdn

Tags: chart.js

I wanted to create a graph which contains a [Time Cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/axes/cartesian/time.html). The docs tell me that I need to use an adapter for a type: 'time' axis. I chose **chartjs-adapter-date-fns**, and imported it using the following cdn:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>`

Now the docs tell me an object must be passed as the adapters.date property of an axis id. But which class/object should I put there? I'm stuck here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using ChartJS 3.4.1 and Chartisan.

```
                      x: {
                            adapters: { 
                                date: { 
                                    // Adapter object here.
                                }
                            },
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day'
                            },
                        },
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-date-fns#configuration) for `chartjs-adapter-date-fns` states:

> date-fns requires a date-fns locale object to be tagged on to each `format()` call, which requires the locale to be explicitly set via the `adapters.date` option

And gives the following example:

```
// import date-fns locale:
import {de} from 'date-fns/locale';

// scale options:
{
    adapters: {
        date: {
            locale: de
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that but unfortanetely I got 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Trying to do the same, but I can't work out how to access the locale object (`de` in the code above) when loading `chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js` from the CDN rather than importing/webpacking it. Any help would be appreciated. I posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739931/configuring-locale-with-bundled-cdn-chartjs-adapter-date-fns-bundle-min-js

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully not too late, but just in case:  I grappled with this, too, and in the end found that you can simply feed chartjs with time scale integers as x values. Convert your timestamps to seconds since the epoch and multiply by 1000, because js uses milliseconds whereas unix uses seconds.

My code is in python, so I convert the timestamp string to milliseconds since the epoch, fist:

```
# get data from backend   
hist = self.backend_get(f"/{name}/history")     
# convert format for chart, filter out None
data_l = [{'x' : 1000*int(datetime.fromisoformat(d['timestamp']).strftime('%s')), 
                   'y' : d['value']} for d in hist if d['value'] is not None]
label = "<insert your label>"
```

Now construct the data

```
        data = {
            'type': 'line',
            'data': {
                'labels': [],
                'datasets': [{
                    'label': label,
                    'data': data_l,
                    }]
                },
            'options': {
                'scales': {
                    'x': {
                        'type': 'time',
                        'time': {'unit': 'day'},
                    },
                },
            },
        }
```

Finally insert the charts js and canvas into the html:

```
        html_s += '''
            <div>
              <canvas id="myChart" class="history_canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script>
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, 
        '''
        html_s += f'{data}'
        html_s += '''
                );
            </script>
            <h3>Raw data</h3>         
        '''
```

[image: time scale data using ms since epoch as x values]

PS I think this only works in Unix because of the epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just adding the cdn was sufficient. The problem was that the labels weren't in date format but in relative time instead ("2 hours ago" instead of 20-07-2021)